# How do I get the ς (final sigma) symbol?

Tags: symbols

I am trying to get this Symbol [image]

I already tried using Detexify, but to no avail.
Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like a “final sigma”:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\begin{document}

\textvarsigma

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does "final sigma" have to do with `\textvarsigma`? P.S. Nice symbol!

Comment: @manooooh That's how the package calls it. The letter is used in Greek for a sigma falling at the end of a word, hence “final sigma”.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, the best way to get the upright ς is to load `unicode-math`.  Here are a few of the different commands the package supports for it in math mode:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\( \mupvarsigma \symup\varsigma \symup{^^^^03c2} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern Math sample]

Either `fontspec` or any package that loads it (including `unicode-math`) will let you enter the Unicode character in text mode as well, but only if your text font contains the character.

If you’re required to use PDFLaTeX, there are a few legacy 8-bit fonts that include an upright Greek font.  You might check the documentation of `isomath` for some options.

If you load a font encoding that includes the character (such as `\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}` in legacy NFSS), PDFTeX will also be able to understand the Unicode character in text mode.

Answer (score 3):

To me the symbol also reminds to this indicated or called final sigma.

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\begin{document}
\char115 
\end{document}
```